# Highcharts drilldown not working when module is imported react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, drilldown

I am new to react/ES6. I am using highcharts 4.2.4 with react in ES6 by creating a highcharts component as given in: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react. I am using ES6 and importing highcharts as import Highcharts from 'highcharts' where highcharts is a npm module mentioned in package.json.

I went through the highcharts drilldown examples. I took the chart given the drilldown example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/ having the following chartOptions:

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

However , I noticed that though the chart is rendered fine, clicking on any column is not triggering the drilldown. However, if instead of importing Highcharts as above and including the lines:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
```

in the index.html, the drilldown is happening fine. I even tried including the following in the high charts component:

import {drilldown} from /highcharts/modules/drilldown.js'

but was of no help. Could you please suggest where I am going wrong and how to get the highcharts component running with drilldown?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you..edited it a bit..:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the highcharts blog article suggests, you need to load optional modules. They send them in as props but you can do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import drilldown from 'highcharts-drilldown';

const Highchart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    // load modules
    drilldown(Highcharts);

    this.chart = new Highcharts['Chart'](
      findDOMNode(this),
      this.props.options
    );
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    this.chart.destroy();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="in-highchart"></div>
    )
  }
});

export default Highchart;
```

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Derek, this was the part I missed, added drilldown which was  inside the highcharts module itself:
   import drilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown.js';
It is working fine now..:)